# Drop-down list, click direct to new URL, no submit button, posting hidden PHP variables

Tags: php, variables, drop-down-menu, onchange, hidden

I want to make a drop-down list, each selection being a new URL link, where there is no Submit button. Instead the user goes straight to the URL when they select from the drop-down. I can make this work, using the following HTML:

```
<select name="mydropdown" class="class1" onChange="document.location = this.value" value="GO">
        <option value="page1.php">Page1</option>
        <option value="page2.php">Page2</option>
        <option value="page3.php">Page3</option>
</select>
```

However, I also want to post two hidden PHP variables to the selected page, $username and $password.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: There is no attribute `value` available for `<select>` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this by submitting the form by jquery. Also pass the password in encoded format. Check below code ==>

```js
function callredirect(pagename){
    $("#frmdropdown").attr("action",pagename);
    $("#frmdropdown").submit();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="post" id="frmdropdown">
    <input type="hidden" name="username" value="abc" />
    <input type="hidden" name="password" value="password" />
    <select name="mydropdown" class="class1" onChange="callredirect(this.value)" >
        <option value="page1.php">Page1</option>
        <option value="page2.php">Page2</option>
        <option value="page3.php">Page3</option>
</select>    
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you, that was very helpful

Comment: @MC74 if it is working then please accept this answer.

Comment: OK, happy to - how do I do that? There doesn't seem to be an obvious accept button.

Comment: @MC74 please go through this https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/359687 it will explain you how to accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to pass variables to other page is using the `$_SESSION`, since you don't have form and user doesn't want to know what variables/ values you are passing. [read the docs here about PHP Sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php)

> NOTE: Advise not to pass password through out the page, it make your
>   system vulnerable for attackers. Best practice is verify user in each
>   page if you want or encrypt and store the password.